# Calcular tan-1 en angulos c#?

Tags: c#, algoritmos, matemáticas

Estoy intentando hacer el siguiente calculo pero no me funciona nada de lo que hago

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El calculo de `tan-1(1)` el resultado de la calculadora es de `45 grados` pero no logro obtener dicho resultado en C#.

**Codigo:**

```
Math.Tanh(1);// resultado = 0,761594155955765
Math.Atan(1);//resultado = 0,785398163397448
Math.Tan(1);//1,5574077246549
```

Supongo que debo de realizar alguna operación mas con uno de ellos, pero qué operación y cual utilizar para obtener el resultado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tenes que usar [**Math.Atan(Double)**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.atan?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Math_Atan_System_Double_).

Según la [**documentación de Microsoft**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.atan?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Math_Atan_System_Double_)

> **Devoluciones**
>
> Double
>
> Ángulo, θ, medido en **radianes**, como `-π/2 ≤θ≤π/2`. O bien NaN si `d` es
>   igual a NaN, `-π/2` redondeado a precisión doble (-1,5707963267949) si
>   `d` es igual a NegativeInfinity, o `π/2` redondeado a precisión doble
>   (1,5707963267949) si `d` es igual a

Teniendo en cuenta esto, puede verse que el problema se da porque vos buscas obtener los grados y la función te esta devolviendo radianes.

Para obtener el resultado en grados deberías hacer lo siguiente

```
Math.Atan(1) * 180 / Math.PI; // resultado 45
```